# Hash Match and Nested Loops

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have stored procedure which updates one table with data from another table, joind by some field. And that is super fast with no indexes on the first table. I see in execution plan that Hash Match is performed while joining tables. But when I add 3 indexes to the first table it becomes extremely slow and execution plan show that Nested loops is used instead of Hash Match. Why this happens? Why indexes make a problem? And is there a way to solve it without removing indexes?

Edit: When I put back 2 indexes, and remove the 3. one it is fast again. Third index is the problem, maybe because filed it is based on is nchar(255), too long maybe?

Comment: You can use [HINTS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) like `{ LOOP | MERGE | HASH } JOIN ` Example: `SELECT * FROM tabA HASH JOIN tabB ON ...`

Comment: Maybe you should post some details about the schema and data... Also post the slow execution plan.

Comment: This could be stale statistics or a parameter sniffing issue. The query optimizer then assumes that using the index 3 and Nested Loops is cheap, when in reality the 
number of rows is too high.
As advised above, please post the actual execution plan of the slow query.
See if the "Actual Number of Rows" is close to "Estimated Number of Rows" in that Nested Loops operator (or other expensive operators).